# uitableviewcell get offset after set navigationBarHidden = YES and and a custom bar view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

[THE BUG PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUs6W.png)

This picture is the bug picture,and my code is as follow:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
naviview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
naviview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"fcfcfc"];
naviview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, VIEW_BOUNDS.width, 64);
[self.view addSubview:naviview];

self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, VIEW_BOUNDS.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-62-TABBARHEIGHT) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

self.tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
[self.view insertSubview:_tableView belowSubview:self.naviview];

}
```

if I use `[self.view insertSubview:_tableView belowSubview:self.naviview];` the cell have a offset, buf if i use `[self.view addSubview:_tableView]` the cell will be right. I want to know the reason lead to the offset,someone can tell me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: add table view using autolayout constraints programmatically, table top constraint with top layout guide

Comment: Did you set any section header?

Comment: Try to disable adjust scroll view insest
`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

Comment: @Joshua there is no section header

Comment: @GevorgGhukasyan that doesn't work,i have tried.

Comment: @BigDaddy can you change the color of self.view to check if the offset is from the tableView or is it in the cell

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use `addSubview` then it is getting added on superview and the and frame of tableview will be calculated with view's frame. But in `insertSubView` is getting added behind navView. There might be possibility that tableView frame is getting calculated with different frame.

You can verify it by making tableView frame height 0 and then try using `insertSubView`.

Comment: the frame will still be the self.view it does not actually change.